# How can I use a token from a request for other requests after responding to the first request?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, mediatr

I have a scenario where I need to respond to a request that it's been received and send a response (request?) to another endpoint once internal api calls and logic has completed. The flow looks like this:

External request to my endpoint > endpoint responds to request with accepted > endpoint passes the request on internally > internal logic fetches and handles data from DB > internal logic uses data from DB to send a request back to a different endpoint from the same integration as the first call came from.

I have managed to get it to work using Queued Background Tasks to send the request to the correct internal handler with Mediatr. However in order for it to work I need to add the barer token from the request header to the request object and then use that barer token to validate against the internal API's. I'd like to avoid this since I might run into the issue of the token expiring or not being valid for the internal Api etc.

Request object example:

```
public class ExampleRequest : IRequest, IRequest<ExampleResponse>
    {
        public string? Token { get; set; } //Added for functioning version, want to get rid 
                                           //of it

        public CommonData Data { get; set; }

        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        public string OperationId { get; set; }

        public List<string> ObjectIdentifiers { get; set; }
    } 

public class CommonData 
    {
        public string MessageId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Response object example (response to the call):

```
    public class ExampleResponseForCall
    {
        public CommonData Data { get; set; }

        public string ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Will be accepted/acknowledged
    }
```

Example response object (for final response)

```
    public class ExampleResponse
    {
        public CommonData Data{ get; set; }

        public string ResponseStatus { get; set; }

        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        public string OperationId { get; set; }
    }
```

My current working version looks something like this:

```
**Endpoint:**
      public IActionResult Post(ExampleRequest request)
        {
            var authorization = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

            if (AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(authorization, out var headerValue))
            {
                var scheme = headerValue.Scheme;
                var parameter = headerValue.Parameter;
            }

            var token = headerValue?.Parameter;

            request.Token = token; //I added token as a nullable string on the request obj

            _backgroundTaskQueue.StartTask(request);

            return Ok(new ExampleResponseForCall
            {
                Data = request.Data,
                ResponseStatus = HttpStatusCode.Accepted.ToString()
            });
        }

**Background Task queue:**
      public void StartTask(IRequest request)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Task is starting.");
            _request = request;
            
            Task.Run(async () => await AddTaskAsync(), _cancellationToken);
        }

        private async ValueTask AddTaskAsync()
        {
            await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(BuildWorkItem);
        }

        private async ValueTask BuildWorkItem(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _logger.LogInformation("Task {Guid} is starting.", guid);

            if (_request == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Request for task {Guid} is null.", guid);
                return;
            }
            await _mediator.Send(_request, token);

            _logger.LogInformation("Task {Guid} is complete.", guid);
        }
```

I also have Handlers that can handle the request and Clients for sending requests internally and back to the caller. All of that works when awaiting the internal logic to be handled. However when I'm using the background task queue the internal client fails on the when getting the token here

```
protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateBaseClient()
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClientName);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", 
             $"application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
            AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetToken());
            return client;
        }

    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
            throw new Exception("No HttpContext available when trying to 
            get Token.");

        
     _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue(Constants.AuthenticationSchemeKey, 
     out var scheme);

        if (scheme?.ToString() == Constants.Bearer)
            return GetTokenFromRequest();

        throw new MissingAccessTokenException("Unknown authentication type");
    }
```

My workaround (that I want to get away from) looks like this:

```
protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateBaseClient(string version, string token)
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClientName);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", 
            $"application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
            AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token); //token from requst.Token
            return client;
        }
```

I've tried to pass in the a lot of different things to the Background Task queue (and changing the parameter type to match ofc) but nothing works. I want to have the background task queue generic since I'll be implementing this for other end points as well.

That's a lot of text so TL:DR, I respond to a request but need to use the token from the request for other calls after responding.

Comment: If API1 is calling API2, you want to use an extension grant to avoid that situation.

Comment: `I need to add the barer token from the request header to the request object and then use that barer token to validate against the internal API's.` - Is this a requirement? Why not use separate authentication (generate new token for internal) for internal apis?

Comment: @GHDevOps we don't actually implement identity server in this project, it is handled in another project. We can also use the same token for the call we make to our internal api so we wouldn't need to fetch a new one which it seems like extension grant provides.

Comment: @thewallrus we could generate a new token, but the token will/should be the same since we would be using the same credentials for it. We also get the token from the GetToken function in the example code, but that hasn't returned a token in my tests. I would assume that this is because we have disposed of the HttpContext since we have already returned a response to the initial call, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Yea, that sounds right for the most part. I don't see any issue with the syntax of your code. You are really asking how to reuse a Bearer Token. It is usually implemented as a refresh token at this point (re-using the credentials to generate a new token). But also, you are trying to forward the token, which can have security implications. If your "External request" (client) is allowed to access all of your internal APIs, then the request usually comes from the client (even if the 2nd request isn't user initiated). If the "External request" is not allowed, then you need to authenticate again

Comment: Extension grants are OAuth2 which you can use without IdentityServer. Besides, like the others said, you'll have to handle the refresh which can be tricky and you're technically getting another token anyways.

Comment: @GHDevOps As both you and thewallrus suggested I looked into using a refresh token. However we will not be able to know the login/id and the password/secret for the user who sent the request unless we store that in plain text within the application (which we don't want to do for obvious reasons) or use a very big and weird workaround. So that is not really an option in this case. However, we decided to go with the working solution in the question, even though it is not the prettiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with the working solution provided in the question itself.

Due to how our infrastructure is set up we won't be able to get a refresh token (as suggested by @GHDevOps and @TheWallrus) since we won't be able to get the login/id and password/secret of the user in a safe and reasonable way.

However, the working solution in the question has some drawback which should be analyzed on a case-to-case basis. We know that the Api sending us the requests will fetch a new (relevant) token approximately 10 minutes before the current (relevant) token expires and use the new token for all coming requests. Since the logic we apply before passing on the request to our backend is very simple (just simple remapping) we should rarely run into issues with the token expiring before the request has been sent, and in the rare cases that is has, we will send that information in the request back to the external Api, giving them a chance to resend the original request. If the external Api isn't fetching a new token before the expiration of the current token that might cause the token to expire before reaching the internal Api more often which might be a good thing to look after if you're implementing a similar solution.

The code changes that I made for this to function are just minor refactoring (see below). Hope this help anyone else running into a similar issue!

```
//Endpoint
public IActionResult Post(ExampleRequest request)//Before
    {
        var authorization = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

        if (AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(authorization, out var headerValue))
        {
            var scheme = headerValue.Scheme;
            var parameter = headerValue.Parameter;
        }

        var token = headerValue?.Parameter;

        request.Token = token; //I added token as a nullable string on the request obj

        _backgroundTaskQueue.StartTask(request);

        return Ok(new ExampleResponseForCall
        {
            Data = request.Data,
            ResponseStatus = HttpStatusCode.Accepted.ToString()
        });
    }

public IActionResult Post(ExampleRequest request)
    {
        request.Token = GetToken(Request);//Made into a separate function in the inherited class

        _backgroundTaskQueue.StartTask(request);

        return Ok(new ExampleResponseForCall
        {
            Data = request.Data,
            ResponseStatus = HttpStatusCode.Accepted.ToString()
        });
    }

protected string GetToken(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var authorization = request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];

        _ = AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(authorization, out var headerValue);

        if (headerValue == null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        return string.Equals(headerValue.Scheme, "Bearer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?
            headerValue.Parameter : "";
    }


//Client
protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateBaseClient()//before
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClientName);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", 
         $"application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
        AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetToken());
        return client;
    }

protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateBaseClient(string token = "")
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClientName);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", $"application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
        AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) ?
            await GetToken() : token); //We will only send in a token if we are async
        return client;
    }
```